# Debug Bricked Standing Desk IC Board Issue

Tags: integrated-circuit, debugging

I have an Apex electric adjustable desk Flex I bought in 2017 that got bricked out of the blue while I was raising it up this morning.
I tried performing a reset by holding the down button for 10 seconds but it just makes a repeated clicking sound from the IC board that the attached video shows. Click is emitted about twice per second in my estimation.

How can I figure out what's wrong with it? It may not be easily fixable, but at least I want to understand what's the issue. I assume that it must be something electrical and not mechanical because the desk has been completely stripped down to just the leg and it still won't move.

What I tried so far:

1. Completely strip down the desk to avoid weight related issues
2. Even remove the tabletop to ensure it's nothing to do with the tabletop forcing legs in a bad angle or similar mechanical issue.
3. Tried 'hard reset' as per the user manual several times (unplug one motor cable, press up, then attempt 'normal reset')

Clicking sound on video (50 seconds long): https://youtu.be/DT80XmWoDoA

Images of the IC board/desk components

[image: LED Flashing red][image]

[image: IC Board #2]

[image: IC Board #1]

Comment: Check the motor winding for resistance. If no current is sensed from an open winding, it may click the relays in cycles to alert you to a linear motor failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clicking sound is made by the electromechanical relays on the board (4 black boxes). They have electromagnet inside and it attracts the two or more contacts (they connect/disconnect in order to control the current flow). This switching of contacts is what You hear.

The board might have faulty power semiconductors (if there are any) controlling the motor. Microcontroller probably tries to start the cycle couple times until it sees that it is impossible to move the table.

The fault might be in a board or in the motor (the brush had lifted for example). You would have to had some electronics knoweledge to repair it. It's probably easly flexible.